# Android Studio Terminal has invisible text

Tags: android-studio

When i turn on my notebook with windows 8.1 64 bit today, I realised that text in Android Studio Terminal is invible after half of screen. How can I solve this problem?

when I use gradlew from cmd, works correctly.

[image: invisible text]

EDIT: I found this log about IDE error, looks like a theme error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.intellij.ide.ui.laf.darcula.ui.DarculaSpinnerUI$1.focusLost(DarculaSpinnerUI.java:52)
at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.focusLost(AWTEventMulticaster.java:230)
at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.focusLost(AWTEventMulticaster.java:229)
at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.focusLost(AWTEventMulticaster.java:229)
at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.focusLost(AWTEventMulticaster.java:229)
at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.focusLost(AWTEventMulticaster.java:229)
at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.focusLost(AWTEventMulticaster.java:229)
at java.awt.Component.processFocusEvent(Component.java:6417)
at javax.swing.JFormattedTextField.processFocusEvent(JFormattedTextField.java:613)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6281)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2234)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4881)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2292)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
at java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager.redispatchEvent(KeyboardFocusManager.java:1954)
at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.typeAheadAssertions(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:995)
at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:661)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4752)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2292)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:746)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:697)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:691)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:719)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:717)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:716)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:866)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:654)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:381)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Comment: Does the same happen with the non-Darcula theme?

Comment: yes, this is happening on both, Drakula and Default. So, forget about theme error.

Comment: Latest version of Android Studio?

Comment: last stable version... 2.1. I did a zero install today after this problem, android studio, sdk and java